# XeLaTeX crashing only in AUCTeX

Tags: xetex, emacs, auctex

I'm running xelatex installed from TeXLive 2013 running on Cygwin, and it works fine compiling from the commandline with `xelatex input.tex` or `latexmk`, but for some reason running the same file through AUCTeX's compile command with `C-c C-c` with **TeX-engine** set to **xetex** crashes xelatex with the output of the log file:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013/W32TeX) (format=xelatex 2014.4.9)  9 APR 2014 22:55
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**\input input.tex

! Emergency stop.
 \input input.tex

*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2 strings out of 493918
 17 string characters out of 6151720
 52462 words of memory out of 5000000
 3428 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1144 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 4i,0n,3p,1b,8s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

`` C-c ` `` just says:

`Error occurred after last TeX file closed.`

Does anyone know of any additional configuration I need to do to get AUCTeX working under windows? Or is there a way to run the AUCTeX compile command with some flags to get some more info about why xelatex is exiting?

The relevant parts of my emacs configuration are as follows:

```
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
(setq TeX-engine 'xetex)
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)
```

I would appreciate any help as it would be nice to not have to switch back to the commandline to compile everytime I make changes. Also, if there are more relevant lists or boards I should post this to in order to get help, I would love to know.